# Java - drawing an arrow between two objects with static dimensions

Tags: java, graphics

i'm stuck on following problem;
I have a rectangle (50x40 px lets say, position : x1,y1) and a cirle (radius 30, positin x2,y2). Now I want to draw an arrow between them

```
 void drawArrow(Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,) {
//x1 and y1 are coordinates of circle or rectangle
//x2 and y2 are coordinates of circle or rectangle, to this point is directed the arrow 
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
double dx=x2-x1;
double dy=y2-y1;
double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
g.transform(at);
g.drawLine(0,0,len,0);
g.fillPolygon(new int[] {len, len-ARR_SIZE, len-ARR_SIZE, len},
new int[] {0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE, 0}, 4);
}
```

This Code obviously connects only the specific points of rect and circle ( on this picture i connected the points in the middle http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/arrk.jpg/ ). Do you have any idea how to achieve stg like this? (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/arr2u.jpg/ ) ... my idea was to shorten the length and calculate the new coordinates, but i'm bit struggling with it.

// I call this function this way:

```
drawArrow(g,temp.x+radius/2,temp.y+radius/2,temp2.x+width/2,temp2.y+height/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to set the clipping. If you add your circle and your rect to the clipping, it won't draw on it.

It doesn't solve the problem or drawing the arrow though. To solve this problem, you need to use Shape.getBounds(), figure out the bounds for the rectangle, then calculate the angle to your circle and use trigonometry to find the right spot on the rectangle